# Import CodePen design to wordpress (elementor)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, elementor, codepen

I'm new to CodePen. I've watched a few videos showing how to use the HTML, CSS & java code to import and customize their design.

I can't make it work with their methods.
Does anyone know how to import this one?

The link is:

<codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/RwyzrVj>

Thank you for your time in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following (with button to run pen):

```
[codepen_embed height="300" default_tab="result" slug_hash="RwyzrVj" preview="true" user="prisoner849"]See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/RwyzrVj">
  Nova - Points (color, animation, rotation.order)</a> by Paul (<a href="https://codepen.io/prisoner849">@prisoner849</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.[/codepen_embed]
```

Or the Following (with css and results tabs open):

```
[codepen_embed height="300" default_tab="css,result" slug_hash="RwyzrVj" user="prisoner849"]See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/RwyzrVj">
  Nova - Points (color, animation, rotation.order)</a> by Paul (<a href="https://codepen.io/prisoner849">@prisoner849</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.[/codepen_embed]
```

Or the Following (with js and results tabs open):

```
[codepen_embed height="300" default_tab="js,result" slug_hash="RwyzrVj" user="prisoner849"]See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/RwyzrVj">
  Nova - Points (color, animation, rotation.order)</a> by Paul (<a href="https://codepen.io/prisoner849">@prisoner849</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.[/codepen_embed]
```